# Embedded Neo4j is not reading properties correctly

Tags: neo4j

I've implemented embbeded Neo4j database into my Scala + Play Framework Project.
While I'm reading nodes from database I'm not getting their properties correctly.
Each time I refresh my page I'm adding 2 nodes - with unique IDs. I'm not adding them, when there is already node with such ID. But sometimes while reading, nodes does not have their properties and I'm getting nulls.

Debug method is returning something like this:

```
[debug] application - Node[0] : ?
[debug] application - Node[3] : ?
[debug] application - Node[4] : ?
[debug] application - Node[5] : ?
[debug] application - Node[6] : ?
[debug] application - Node[7] : 786432765
[debug] application - Node[8] : 567987654
```

Another time:

```
[debug] application - Node[0] : ?
[debug] application - Node[3] : ?
[debug] application - Node[4] : ?
[debug] application - Node[5] : 786432765
[debug] application - Node[6] : 567987654
[debug] application - Node[7] : ?
[debug] application - Node[8] : ?
```

Here is some piece of code:

```scala
  def addNode(node: MyNode) {
      var isUnique = true
      val foundUser : Node = nodeIndex.get("phone", node.phone).getSingle()
      if(foundUser != null) {
          Logger.info("FOUND NODE with phone " + node.phone + ": " + foundUser)
          isUnique = false
      } else {
          Logger.info("THERE IS NO NODE WITH PHONE " + node.phone)
      }
    if (isUnique) {
      Logger.info("Node: " + node.phone + " is being added")
      val tx : Transaction = graph.beginTx
      try {
          val newnode: Node = graph.createNode()
          newnode.setProperty("phone", node.phone)
          nodeIndex.add(newnode, "phone", node.phone)
      } catch {
        case e : Exception => {
          tx.failure()
          Logger.error(e.getMessage())
        }
      }
      tx.success()
    } else {
      Logger.info("Node: " + node.phone + " ALREADY EXISTS")
    }
  }

def debug() {

    Logger.debug("Node of " + graph);
    val it = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graph).getAllNodes().iterator()
    while(it.hasNext()) {
      val node : Node = it.next()
      if(node.hasProperty("phone"))
          Logger.debug(node + " : " + node.getProperty("phone"))
      else
          Logger.debug(node + " : ?")

    }
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you call the `tx.finish()` method somewhere ?

Comment: It looks like helped ;) but I will check it more precise tomorrow ;)